# Methods: Pyramid Volume

Tags: java

This is my task that I have to do:

Define a method pyramidVolume with double parameters baseLength, baseWidth, and pyramidHeight, that returns as a double the volume of a pyramid with a rectangular base.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalcPyramidVolume {

public static void pyramidVolume (double baseLength, double baseWidth, double pyramidHeight) {
  baseLength = 1.0;
  baseWidth = 1.0;
  pyramidHeight = 1.0;

  double pyramidVolume = ((baseLength * baseWidth) * pyramidHeight) / 3;
}   

public static void main (String [] args) {
  System.out.println("Volume for 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 is: " + pyramidVolume(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
  return;
}
}
```

I can edit only the section of code where I created the pyramidVolume method call. I am getting an error that says 'void' type not allowed here and it is pointing the to system.out line which i can not edit. I am very confused on why it is giving me an error on that line.

Comment: Maybe arrange for `pyramidVolume()` to return `double`, not `void`?

Comment: Your method pyramidVolume() returns void which caused the problem.

Comment: Change to `public static double pyramidVolume(-)` and `return pyramidVolume`.

Comment: **Your** description says: "*... that returns as a double  the volume ...*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyramidVolume` return type is `void`. Change return type to `double` as below:

```
public static double pyramidVolume (double baseLength, double baseWidth, double pyramidHeight) {

  double pyramidVolume = ((baseLength * baseWidth) * pyramidHeight) / 3;
  return pyramidVolume;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! also, I feel very dumb for asking this, but would that volume formula work? because it passes one test but does not pass the other, which makes me think it is the formula?

Comment: For some reason, it is not displaying the test inputs. The first test passed because the expected value was 0.3333333333 and thats what I got. However, the second test had an expected value of 46.39999999 and I got 0.33333333 again. But it is not displaying any test inputs which is weird

Comment: I guess thats why it says watch out for integer division

Comment: updated the code. basically length, width and height were always 1.0

Comment: You have to remove those extra lines that you had inside the method, that set everything to `1.0`.  That's why you were always getting `0.3333333` as the volume.

Answer (score -1):

```
static double calcPyramidVolume(double baseLength, double baseWidth, double 
pyramidHeight) {
double Volume, baseArea;
baseArea = baseLength * baseWidth;
Volume = baseArea * pyramidHeight * 1/3;
return Volume;
}
```

is actually the correct code for this assignment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).